# Disabling the security certificate unknown warning in Firefox

Tags: firefox, security

How do I disable the security certificate unknown/untrusted warning in Firefox (the state where it asks you to add an exception)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to completely disable this warning in Firefox, for every site?

Answer (score 1):

The "[Remember Certificate Exception](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10246)" addon should do it for you, but I would recommend turning it off whenever you're planning to use your credit card.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the discussion "[Need to disable the invalid security certificate screen](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1017125&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a)" (forum post on [MozillaZine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MozillaZine)).